# What is the shortcut for switching XML view?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xml-layout

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I switch between these 3 tabs using **keyboard shortcut**?

Earlier it was working with

> alt + shift + left/right arrow

But now with android studio's new version, it is not working.

I am using Ubuntu, but these shortcuts are also same for the Windows system I think.

It's really frustrating when you are writing code and you have to use your mouse for this simple stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of android studio is this ?

Comment: `alt + shift + left/right arrow` works fine with windows

Comment: @PraveenSP Android Studio 3.6.1

Comment: @Flying Dutchman this will switch between views, like from file1 to file2, not within file1

Comment: as @FlyingDutchman said the combination worked for me also i.e I was able to switch between one file... BTW I am using Android Studio 3.6.2 It would be better if you update and check it once...

Comment: `alt+arrows` used for switch between tabs, `shift+alt+arrows` switch like `code,split and design` in xml

Comment: Can you show that via a screenshot in Keymap settings? @FlyingDutchman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what my keymap set to in windows for Android studio 3.6.2

**For Switch between tabs**

[image: Between tabs]

**For Swith between multieditor file**

[image: Between multieditor]

Comment: Actually the problem was that "Default for GNOME" keymap was selected, so now I selected "Default for Windows"

Comment: @KishanSolanki yeh I saw that option in mine but I just ignored it ;)